# Segue to detail view controller on landscape mode

Tags: swift, segue, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm using **UISPlitViewController** in order to show categorized data on the screen. I implemented a search method on master view controller and the flow of data is fine on the iPhone screen, but on the iPad, portrait and landscape, It does work as I want.

I have create a segue (the black arrow points it) to detail controller but it loads data into master view controller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let object = categoryID[indexPath.row]
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailTableViewController
            controller.detailItem = object as Int?
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    //this is the problem!
    }else if segue.identifier == "showSearchDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let object = searchResultDrugsID[indexPath.row]
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DrugDetailsTableViewController
            controller.detailItem = object as Int?
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my storyboard:
[image]

Here is the normal behavior:
[image]

And here is where the problem lies, I want to load data in detail view controller when user clicks on search results:
[image]

Comment: The master view should be a table that slides to another table view (in the same frame), then from there, go to the detail view?

Comment: It does not slide to another table in the master view, it just reload different data when user types in search bar.

Comment: What I am saying is you are showing click in master, go to submenu in detail then click to get to detail page. It should be click in master, slides to submenu in master, click to detail.

Comment: well, its default behavior is like what you mentioned, like the first demo, but the second one is a bit different; When user clicks on a row in the master it should [what I want] show data in the detail view.

Comment: Make sure that the segue pointed by the arrow is "Show Detail (eg Replace)".

Comment: @bubuxu Thank you, there is weird bug in IB, when I changed the segue to "Show Detail" it didn't work first time, I had to change to something else then change it to "Show Detail" again then it worked.

Comment: @Maysam that's what I want to you double check because created a project to re-produce what you did and in my project, the Selection of the search result cell segue works correctly (which is replacing the detail view controller).

Comment: Yes, now it pushes the view into detail section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Too many Navigation Controllers, too many segues.

From the storyboard screen shot, I can only assume that you may have mixed and matched `detail` view controllers improperly. Specifically, the one with the black arrow shouldn't be there.

You probably do not need (and shouldn't have) both a `"showDetail"` and a `"showSearchDetail"`: searching is merely reducing the scope of what's available in the Master view, which is the expected user experience.
An excellent resource on the topic is [Candy Search](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial) from raywenderlich.com, with an excellent example and tutorial.

Creating a default Master-Detail project from Xcode yields this structure:

[image: 5 views master-detail]

To add a `UISearchController` to that, build it programmatically in your master `UITableViewController`:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
definesPresentationContext = true
```

and filter the results from the `UISearchResultsUpdating` delegate:

```
extension MasterViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
  func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filter(searchController.searchBar.text!)
  }
}

func filter(_ searchText: String) {
  // Your filter goes here
  tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Also, details segues should "Show Details"

[image: Proper segue]

Comment: My question is clearly about pushing data to detailViewController, not implementing search controller.

Comment: What i'm looking for is keeping search controller in the master view and push data to detail view.

Comment: Yes, It's loading the view in the wrong location. Can't I have several segues to different view controllers from a master view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131952/discussion-between-swiftarchitect-and-maysam).